# Can't access spring bean inside redisson schedule task

Tags: redisson

I am using redisson task scheduler, it works well but now we require to use spring bean inside it. We have tried to Autowire bean, but it doesn't work. Issue might be due to Redisson class loader not sure.
Is it a limitation of it? Do we have any workaround to achieve this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order solve issue to access spring beans inside redisson task. I have used redisson RemoteService which give facility to register the class and it is easily accessible from redissonClient whenever require.

Thanks